# Did salesforce changed sender profile implementation? Bugs for me

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, bug

Today a message of salesforce popped up:

[image]

Unfortunately it popped up after we had a journey activity that had send emails.
**We changed nothing** at our sender profiles (that work with ampscript) or the scripts[code snippet content blocks].

---

How we set sender profiles:

- ContentBlockByKey inside the sender profile for fromname and fromemail (with 2 different ampscripts)
- `%%=v(@var)=%%` at the end of the Ampscript to print the value that is set by the ampscript logic.

This has never been a problem but today our newsletter looked like this in the sender section:

- `<!----> Business Name<!----> <!---->`

For test sends and journey builder email send activities we get the behaviour i described above, for normal sends it works like before.

- The particular sender profile is marked as **verified**.

---

Ampscript looks like (shortened) and dots (...) added. [It is working and was working correct for the last 6 month since it was coded, you can still tell me what to improve though ;)]:

```
%%[

var @fromName
var @profileName
set @defaultName = "XXX"

set @country = [country]
set @language = [language]

set @country = UpperCase(@country)
set @language = UpperCase(@language)

/* Germany */
IF @country == "DEU" THEN
 IF @language == "DE" THEN
  set @profileName = Concat(@country,"_",@language,"_PROFILE")
 ELSE
  set @profileName = "DEU_DE"
 ENDIF
ELSEIF ... THEN
/* some comment */
ELSEIF ...  THEN 
/* some comment */
...
ELSE
 set @profileName = "DEFAULT"
ENDIF  

set @fromName = LookUp("PROFILE_DEX","FromName","SendProfileName",@profileName)
set @fromName = IIF(EMPTY(@fromName),@defaultName,@fromName)
]%%

%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

What can I do that this weird html comments do not show?

Comment: Our dynamic sender profile works fine, just did a test via Journey Builder. Although in our configuration we use ContentBlockByName. Anyway, in your content block, are you printing the values out properly? Like %%=v(@fromName)=%% and using the same in sender profile?

Comment: Thank you for testing. Yes, thats exactly what we do. Some big ampscript blog starting with %%[ and ending with ]%% after that it just follows %%=v(@var)=%%, like stated in the post.

Comment: Try copying script and the print-out variables to an Email template and do a subscriber preview. If you see the variables being populated correctly. In case it works, as experiment you can try creating a new Sender Profile with same configuration and test using that.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the AMPscript block? Does it contain those HTML comments anywhere inside it or do you believe they being added via the execution of the SFMC conteblock call function? Is it an HTML content block? Code Snippet?

Comment: The content block is a code snippet not an html content block. I do have many comments in it (33) that look like inline comments `// comment` but they are all inside the AmpscriptBlock.

Comment: one thing to note is that `//` does not function in AMPscript as an inline comment, like it does in JS. You are required to use `/* */` on ALL comments. Not sure that is what is causing your issue, but was something worth noting.

Comment: Are you sure about your last comment? Every amp syntax checker I have tested marked it as comment. I will test it and write real ampscript functions in the code to test if it gets invoked. Meanwhile Salesforce has admitted that there is nothing wrong with my script but they have screwed a new implementation. I will post this an answer when I know more about it with research and development. First impression is that a Call of ampscript like contentblockbykey inside sender profiles fromname causes this issue. When you write the script in there the error should not pop up. Further testing needed.

Comment: if you use `%%[ set @fname = "fname" // set @fname = "Germany " ]%%` (with correct formatting) outputting `%%=v(@fname)=%%` it would output: `Germany` not `fname`. Which means it is not acting as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has admitted that they have screwed up their implementation.

> Hi Johannes,
>
> My name is XXX, and I'm the Tier 2 Developer Support agent who's
>   taken ownership of this case. Our team is aware of this issue and is
>   currently working to resolve it. As a short-term workaround, can you
>   please try copying your AMPScript from your content blocks and placing
>   it directly in the from name and from email of your sender profile?
>   ...
>
> Thank you,
>
> XXX XXX
>
> Success Agent - Tier 2
>
> Salesforce Technical Support

So for all that use the configuration like I have described in my question, it will create this error.

---

**Solution is not like stated in the comment from support:**

1. `%%[ContentBlockByKey("sender-profile")]%%%%=v(@fromEmail)=%%`

   1. Deleting the `%%=v(@fromEmail)=%%` from the ampscript itself

> Posting your complete ampscript into the fromname and fromemail of the
>   sender profile will cause errors when you try to save it into the
>   sender profile. Atleast for me.