# Warning, verify your from addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud

[image]As per the pop-up message, all the From Addresses, Sender Profiles, Users need to be verified to ensure send restrictions don't restrict user workflow(does that mean email delivery or anything else?). We have over 50 active Business Units in our account, each BU consists of an average of 100 sender profiles and we raised a support ticket regarding steps to be taken on this. Support has confused us and suggested that we verify our Sender profiles, From Addresses. My concern is that  we have many users who have sender profiles in multiple BUs. If we start manually verifying those(which itself is a very time taking task considering the number of BUs that we have), many of our users will start receiving multiple emails to verify their email addresses. My client is not in the favor of sending multiple emails as some of the email addresses used in sender profiles in multiple BUs belong to high profile people.  We contacted our account representative too but they have asked to contact support again.

What impact does not verifying Sender profiles and/or From Address have on delivery of our emails? Should we also go to every individual user account setting and verify their email address as well(if yes, then why is this required and if no, then the user will see this pop-up message every single time they login to their account until they verify their email address).

Has anyone taken any steps after they received this pop-up after the SFMC release? I see a question by @johannes [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249830/did-salesforce-changed-sender-profile-implementation-bugs-for-me) but we are not using dynamic sender profiles in most of the cases.

We are not even sure if we need to take any action on this pop-up message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to deal with this a few weeks ago as well.

In case your Sender Profiles and From Addresses are in a domain that is verified (with either SAP or Private Domain) then after clicking Verify, it will automatically get marked as Verified. **There will be no verification-Email sent**.

[image: Auth]

The confirmation Email is only sent in case the domain is external and isn't part of your SAP or Private Domains.

As for your other question - on separate SFMC Users the Email verification is only required if they are sending Emails from their Email address with Marketing Cloud, though just like with previous point - in case the domain is already part of SAP/Private Domain, it will be automatically marked as verified after clicking the verify button.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Rain. We have one verified domain for our Marketing cloud account and the sender profiles under that got automatically verified. But for other sender profiles, are we required to verify each one of those? And if a user is sending emails from Marketing cloud, should we let all the users know to verify their email addresses? If they don't verify, what impact will that have on their emails? To sum up, what exactly should we do here(verify all sender profiles/from addresses/users?) so that no email goes to spam or undelivered.

Comment: Ideally yes, if the other Sender Profiles that aren't using the SFMC Authenticated domain they should each be verified. Including SFMC Users who may have a reason to send from their personal Email with Marketing Cloud. Salesforce will be restricting Email sends from not-verified addressed in coming months. There will be Email Deliverability Readiness webinar about it next week. More information - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000274530&type=1

Comment: If this is the case, then it is really scary for us because not all the users have admin access in order to verify themselves. We are then left with no option but to do it manually for every user and sender profile(should not be the ideal way given the huge volume of users and profiles the accounts have). @Rain are you able to access the links https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_from_address_management.htm&type=5 or https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_domain_registration.htm&type=5 contained in the link that you shared here? I am getting 404 not found.

Comment: It seems they are once again migrating the documentation around, almost all of the SFMC documentation links are down, including the ones you linked to and Release Notes. Through Google buffer I see the following what might be of interest to you > "Two Domain Verification APIs to support the new domain registration feature for email in Marketing Cloud. Use domain registration to easily register your non-authenticated domains and avoid the need to send a verification email to each From address that is not authenticated or registered."